# Problem with multiple scrollviews in Android?

Tags: android, nested, scrollview

I am facing a problem with nested scrollviews in Android.

I have a scrollview(vertical) in a screen as parent scrollview.  Inside this parent scrollview I added tw more child scrollviews (both are vertical).  When I scroll up or down at any place only parent scrollview is working fine but not in the child views.

Can any one help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should control the "focusable" and "clickable" parametres. If an item A of the list has a controllable subitem B, the item A can't be controlled.

Comment: Can i have any example please?

Comment: Please, think - how the application can tell an attempt to control the inner list from controlling the outer list?  You should invent some switch for it. That switch should make one list "focusable" and "clickable" and the other - not "focusable" and "clickable".